# Why does my MATLAB function not agree with my calculator?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a function for MATLAB and I just don't see how to set it up right. I set up the function and then I do it manually with a calculator and I seem to get a different answer. I am sure it is the way I set it up. If someone can point out the problem I would greatly appreciate it.

I am trying to make the following function:

```
x*e^(cos(x))
```

what I wrote in MATLAB:

```
function y = fun2(a)

  y = a*exp(cos(a))

end
```

Comment: A couple of tips for the future. I changed mathlab into MATLAB. I'm pretty sure this is not mathlab. Also, when you ask a question like this, provide the inputs that you used, and the outputs. When you say you get two different answers, show us what those answers are. That's always useful. Without that information, we may have to guess.

Comment: You asked the question, but have been quiet since. Do you still need help?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is just fine. The most likely explanation is that your calculator is in `deg` mode and so treats the argument to `cos` as an angle measured in degrees. Computer code like MATLAB code always use radians rather than degrees. Switch your calculator to `rad` mode and the two evaluations will agree.